# Encrypting files on Windows Mobile

Tags: .net, encryption, windows-mobile

I am currently working on a .NET project which is deployed to Windows Mobile 5/6 devices.
We would like to protect our property intellectual rights by preventing the code from being reverse engineered.

I have experimented with several Obfuscation tools, but have found that when we log stack traces (e.g an exception has been thrown), important information is being lost due to the obfuscation.

The solution we’re currently looking at is to use encryption. We can’t use the SD card encryption which comes with Windows Mobile because we have lots of devices out in the field which do not have SD cards installed in them.

Can anybody recommend a way of deploying files to a PDA which have already been encrypted which can be used by the PDA.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there are no other options as the one you already found:

1. use a code obfuscator to encrypt the code. Do this after all bugs and exceptions are fixed and usefull messages show for known exceptions.
2. Store and run your app from encrypted SD Card. The SD card can not be read except for in the original device.

Possibly you can make a loader app that reads an encrypted byte stream (your application) and save that as temporary executable file and then launches this executable. At the end of the executable, your loader can delete the temporary exe file.